# How to return response in laravel from trait?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.1, laravel-5

I have controller:

```
class UserController extends Controller
{
    public function index(){
        return '1';
    }
}
```

now I want return code from trait like:

```
class UserController extends Controller
{

    use SomeTrait;
    public function index(){
        $this->traitMethod();

        return 2;
    }
}

trait SomeTrait
{
    public function traitMethod(){
        if($this->something == 1){
            return '1';
        }else{
            View::share('somethingElse', 2);
        }
    }
}
```

In UserController if `$something = 1`, trait should return `1` and rest of `UserController` should't be executed, how can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

This this:

```
class UserController extends Controller
{

    use SomeTrait;
    public function index(){
        $this->traitMethod() ? : return 2;
        // if you don't want to return 2, you may return null or something else
        }

        return 2;
    }
}

trait SomeTrait
{
    public function traitMethod(){
        if($this->something == 1){
            return false;
        }else{
            View::share('somethingElse', 2);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: trait is used 10 times, and this code "if(!$this->traitMethod(){
            return 2;
        }"  then will be repeated 10 times so this in not good solution.

Comment: I've updated the code, this solution is much shorter. Also, if `something == 1`, do you need to return something (create a view, for example or redirect user somewhere) or just terminate the request?